# Missing operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, operators

In quantum mechanics, we have the momentum operator which relies on the gradient $\nabla$ for its expression $-i\hbar \nabla$, and the angular momentum operator whose expression $-i\hbar\textbf{r}\times\nabla$ involves a curl. Is there an operator that would be $-i\hbar\nabla\cdot$ (where $\cdot$ means "divergence")?

This operator would calculate, for a wavefunction $\psi(\textbf{r})$: $-i\hbar(\frac{\partial\psi_x}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial\psi_y}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial \psi_z}{\partial z})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost, take into account the misinterpretations you are making that @knzhou discusses in their answer.

As a secondary issue, let me mention an example of an operator similar to what you mention. One trivial example is $p^2$, which in the position representation is proportional to the laplacian, which you can always write as the divergence of the gradient.

A less trivial one is the following:

When working with magnetic fields, you'll have Hamiltonians that look like $H=\frac{1}{2m} \left(p-\frac{e}{c}A\right)^2+V$, where $A$  is the vector potential. When you expand it, you produce terms of the form $A \cdot p$ or $p \cdot A$, which commute if $\nabla \cdot A = 0$. In the position representation we have
\begin{equation}
\langle x | p \cdot A |\psi\rangle = - i \hbar \nabla \cdot \left[ A \psi(x) \right] \, .
\end{equation}

For more details, take a look of section 5.3 in Sakurai's book, Modern Quantum Mechanics, on the Zeeman effect.

Comment: Yeah, but that's just because $\mathbf{A}$ is a vector. Once you expand $\nabla \cdot (\mathbf{A} \psi)$ with the product rule you can only get things like $\nabla \psi$.

Comment: I don't disagree, but I think it matches the parameters of the question.

Comment: @knzhou Let me edit to make emphasis on the very valid cautions you discuss.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can only take the divergence of a vector field, and a wavefunction is a scalar. The angular momentum is not the curl either; curl is $\nabla \times$ while you have $\mathbf{r} \times \nabla$.

Answer (score 1):

Silly question: in QM, the wavefunction $\Psi$ is a function $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, and div applies only to vector fields.